# How to show input field that added by jquery after validation or page load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

In my form I have a button called Add more field and it adds a input field by jquery. When i send data to the server for validate then all the added fields are not showing. Is this possible to showing field and value of them after validation from server, i am using PHP for server side validation.

This is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=1;  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
       i++;  
       $('#dynamic_field').append(
        '<div id="rmv'+i+'"><div class="tutor-row clearfix"><div class="tutor-col12" id="subject-addmore-error"><div class="form-group addmoresubject"> <input class="form-control" id="subject-addmore" type="text" name="subject[]" placeholder="Subject"><a type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="addmore btn_remove" style="color: white;background-color: #d60303 !important;">Remove</a></div></div></div></div>');  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#rmv'+button_id+'').remove();  
  }); });
```

Comment: shure, you can use ajax to send data to server and on sucess (i mean php returned code 200) you can perform some additional checks on returned body if needed and then implement add your logic

Comment: ajax should work